# Compression and Lookup of huge list of words

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, compression

I have a huge list of multi-byte sequences (lets call them words) that I need to store in a file and that I need to be able to lookup quickly. Huge means: About 2 million of those, each 10-20 bytes in length.

Furthermore, each word shall have a *tag* value associated with it, so that I can use that to reference more (external) data for each item (hence, a spellchecker's dictionary is not working here as that only provides a hit-test).

If this were just in memory, and if memory was plenty, I could simply store all words in a hashed map (aka dictionary, aka key-value pairs), or in a sorted list for a binary search.

However, I'd like to compress the data highly, and would also prefer not to have to read the data into memory but rather search inside the file.

As the words are mostly based on the english language, there's a certain likelyness that certain "sillables" in the words occur more often than others - which is probably helpful for an efficient algorithm.

Can someone point me to an efficient technique or algorithm for this?

Or even code examples?

**Update**

I figure that DAWG or anything similar routes the path into common suffixes this way won't work for me, because then I won't be able to tag each complete word path with an individual value. If I were to detect common suffixes, I'd have to put them into their own dictionary (lookup table) so that a trie node could reference them, yet the node would keep its own ending node for storing that path's tag value.

In fact, that's probably the way to go:

Instead of building the tree nodes for single chars only, I could try to find often-used character sequences, and make a node for those as well. That way, single nodes can cover multiple chars, maybe leading to better compression.

Now, if that's viable, how would I actually find often-used sub-sequences in all my phrases?
With about 2 million phrases consisting of usually 1-3 words, it'll be tough to run all permutations of all possible substrings...

Comment: 20 bytes * 2 million = 40Mb. That's miniscule compared to the typical amount of memory in a computer. If you store them in a sorted array, you will use binary search for lookup, and you will hardly need any additional memory at all.

Comment: Yep, 40mb isn't much. And if it's speed you are concerned about, then keep the data in memory as plain as possible.

Comment: As written below, the 40MB have to come with the app, and I like to keep the app's download size much smaller. Plus, that's not the only partion. There's a larger portion of another set of "words", which doesn't need to be searchable but still compressable because it'll amount to about 1GB in raw strings. Once I found a suitable algo for the above, I hope to use it on this other, larger, set as well.

Comment: Besides, why assume I might not want to use this on a device that has far less memory to play with than a typical PC? iPhone, embedded, and so on, all could be part of this.

Comment: @Thomas I think the suggestions come from continuously looking how people micro or prematurely optimize things. Many people could suspect something like that going on when reading your phrase *I'd like to compress the data highly* without further explanations.

Comment: @belisarius: yeah, that'll teach me trying to be concise ;)

Comment: Knuth said: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil". Which wouldn't apply here, as this is not a matter of a small efficiency. 40MB is still larger than the average size of app in it's entirety. Nor is it premature - size constraints or sensitivity is something that can be known before any coding is done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There exists a data structure called a trie. I believe that this data structure is perfectly suited for your requirements. Basically a trie is a tree where each node is a letter and each node has child nodes. In an letter based trie, there would be 26 children per node.

Depending on what language you are using this may be easier or better to store as a variable length list while creation.

This structure gives:
a) Fast searching. Following a word of length n, you can find the string in n links in the tree.
b) Compression. Common prefixes are stored.

Example: The word BANANA and BANAL both will have B,A,N,A nodes equal and then the last (A) node will have 2 children, L and N. Your Nodes can also stored other information about the word.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Andrew JS

Comment: I had a hunch that this would be what the answer would be. While I've never handled a trie expressly, I had an idea that this is what it would look like. Still, I wonder, to manage the tree, each node has to carry a _list_ of all its children. In a compact file or memory form, this would mean that, provided the tree exceeds 1MB in size, I'll need a 32 bit pointer plus the size of the child's name (in a tree organized by single bytes this would be one byte). I wonder if this won't lead to excessive memory consumtion due to this housekeeping.

Comment: @Thomas - check out the video I posted.  It's about a file used by a boggle AI that contains a DAWG (similar to a Trie but more sophisticated).  You don't need 32 bits to store the pointer - you can be a little more clever (offsets and bitfields).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a Trie or a DAWG (directed acyclic word graph).  There is a great lecture from Stanford on doing exactly what you want here: http://academicearth.org/lectures/lexicon-case-study

Comment: Thanks for the video pointer. A bit long stretched (I could skip a lot of the basics), but explains well all the design thoughts behind it. I also figure classic DAWG won't work - I've added explanations to my original post about that.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the paper ["How to sqeeze a lexicon"](http://www.n3labs.com/pdf/lexicon-squeeze.pdf). It explains how to build a minimized finite state automaton (which is just another name for a DAWG) with a one-to-one mapping of words to numbers and vice versa. Exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I need distinct ending node for each path. See my original (improved) post why.

Comment: With the FSA in this paper you get a unique (and dense) number for each path. Aou can use this number to store associated iinformation externally e.g. in an array, in a database or in a file with fixed record length.

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with Indexed file.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I think I am well familiar with the concept of indexed files. I've learned that ca. 1982, I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just using a hash map? Thing is, on a modern OS architecture, the OS will use virtual memory to swap out unused memory segments to disk anyway. So it may turn out that just loading it all into a hash map is actually efficient.

And as jkff points out, your list would only be about 40 MB, which is not all that much.

Comment: 40MB is much if I have to include it in the download of my app. I expect it to be popular :)

Comment: Also, I try to keep the memory footprint _on disk_ low. A hash table won't be of help there.